# Could Attention_mask in T5 be a float in [0,1]?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism, huggingface

I was inspecting T5 model from hf https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5 . attention_mask is presented as

```
attention_mask (torch.FloatTensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length), optional) — Mask to avoid performing attention on padding token indices. Mask values selected in [0, 1]:
1 for tokens that are not masked,
0 for tokens that are masked.
```

I was wondering whether it could be used something "softer" not only selecting the not-padding token but also selecting "how much" attention should be used on every token.

This question is related to the one proposed here [Can the attention mask hold values between 0 and 1?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/can-the-attention-mask-hold-values-between-0-and-1/111303#111303)

Do you know if such attention_mask vector is used in any other ways where a non integer value could harm the model?

Thank you for your precious time and advices.